# Illustrator reverse character without creating outlines

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

Is it possible to reverse (as in flip vertically) a single character (in my case the '~' character) inside a line of text WITHOUT converting the text to outlines? As in it's still a character, it just happens to be reveresed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rotate a character - which may or may not work for you. There's no way to "flip" a character though.

To rotate, simply select the character and alter the option fields in the **Character Panel**. You may need to choose `Show Options` from the **Character Panel Menu** first.

[image]

Here, I've adjusted the baseline shift as well to bring the rotated character back down to the baseline of the other characters.

In Illustrator CC, you can click the **Touch Type Tool** button on the **Character Panel** to alter text with click-dragging. It still doesn't allow you to "flip" the character, but you can more easily adjust rotation, placement, and size of individual characters this way.

[image]

These are pretty much the only transformation you can make to a *single character* in a line of live type.

Comment: Nice feature (never noticed it before despite using illustrator for ~10 years), but not quite what I was looking for. Have a +1 though

Comment: @chrism if it answers your question then why not except it or explain why the said above isn't an acceptable answer please.